# Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView - Scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`:

```
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/_100sdp"

                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:background="@color/bright_grey"

                ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

My `RecyclerView` is being filled with items in `onCreate()`

On a device you would see the first item of the `RecyclerView` on the very top und would have to scroll down the `NestedScrollView` in order to see the last item.

Since my items are chat message sorted by the time sent I need the `NestedScrollView` to be scrolled all the way down so users would see the latest chat message first without having to scroll in the first place.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is that your entire layout? Or did you omit some other views inside the NestedScrollView?

Comment: My RecyclerView is the only child of my NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your `RecyclerView` is the only child of your `NestedScrollView`, you would be better off removing the `NestedScrollView` altogether, and instead applying the fixed height to the `RecyclerView`. Something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:background="@color/bright_grey" />
```

Doing this allows you to have the RecyclerView itself manage scrolling, rather than the parent scroll view. And *that* allows you to leverage a property of `LinearLayoutManager` to achieve what you want.

Reverse layout -- setting this will "invert" your list; the first item in your adapter will appear at the bottom of the list, and the default scroll position of the `RecyclerView` will be to scroll all the way to the bottom.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)

```
LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
lm.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used `setStackFromEnd` instead of `setReverseLayout` since I only want the view to show the last item and not change the layout direction. 
The changes messed with most of my elements (their layout) but I guess that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same issue and want to keep the NestedScrollView.
It will work like this.

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                        binding.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(
                            0,
                            binding.recyclerview.measuredHeight,
                            500
                        )
                        // binding.nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, binding.recyclerview.measuredHeight)
                        // binding.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, binding.recyclerview.measuredHeight)
                    }, 50L)
```

*For me, it didn't work without delay.*